# DropDownList in Repeater control, can't fire SelectedIndexChanged first Time selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Here are my codes:

**.aspx**

```
<tr>
<td><%#Eval("StoreInventoryItemName") %></td>
 <td>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBrandEdit" runat="server" Width="100%" ClientIDMode="AutoID" CssClass="form-control " AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GetValue"  EnableViewState="true"/>
</td>
<tr>
```

**.cs**

```
protected void rptrMasterList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
 {
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
      DropDownList ddlBrandEdit = (e.Item.FindControl("ddlBrandEdit") as DropDownList);      

               ddlBrandEdit.DataSource = Obj.MaterialBrands_SelectAll();
                ddlBrandEdit.DataTextField = "MaterialBrandsName";
                ddlBrandEdit.DataValueField = "MaterialBrandsID";                         
                ddlBrandEdit.DataBind();
      }

 }
```

First time selection from dropdown list not firing postback,it just collapse table design,
the second time selection from dropdown list postback is working ,please help me if any one know about this
this repeater inside the updatepanel the code is below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelList" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

Comment: What does it mean `it just collapse table design`, do you have client side code that does that?

Comment: -i have a table initialization script, that not working that why it breaking the table design on selected index change ,if does post back happened it will work .i just calling the script from code behind-